# Editing UITextField in UITableView (enable/disable input)?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextfield, edit

Im trying to achieve something similar to Apples Contact.app.

When the user press Edit in the detail view the textfields should become enabled, and when the user presses Done/Save then the input UITextFields should be disabled.

So I added:

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    return [(UITableView*)self.view isEditing];
}
```

And set the controller to be the delegate for every textfield, but if the users presses Done/Save while editing is taking place the keyboard stays open and the user can edit the string. How can i make sure that this not happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by setting the delegate of the textfield to the cell, and implementing these methods.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if (!editing)
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    return [self isEditing];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you handled only the beggining of the edit ... you should record which uitextbox is the first responder then if you tap the save button you should invoke a resignFirstResponder on the texbox.

Hope this helps,
Moszi